# emmeans giving large standard errors for negative binomial model

Tags: r, lsmeans

I have a dataset with 5 replicates (`batch`) of a 6 treatments (`trt`), each treatment has 5 associated treatment times (`time`) with the treatment time for controls being 0. Several treatments in batch 1 failed and were dropped from the dataset. From each treatment x time combination there is an associated number of "bad" results (`bad`) out of a total sample (`total`). The total sample is 10 for *almost* all of the treatments, two treatments had smaller samples due to sampling errors.
I am trying to fit a negative binomial model with `bad` as the response variable and `trt` and `time` as predictors. The data look like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
# create dataset
data.frame(
  batch=c(rep("A",11),rep("B",26),rep("C",26),rep("D",26),rep("E",26)),
  trt=c("ctrl",rep("trt1",5),rep("trt5",5),rep(c("ctrl",rep("trt1",5),rep("trt2",5),rep("trt3",5),rep("trt4",5),rep("trt5",5)),4)),
  time=c(0,c(2:6)*5,c(1:5)*5,rep(c(0,rep(c(2:6)*5,3),rep(c(1:5)*5,2)),4)),
  bad=c(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,3,0,2,0,1,2,3,2,1,1,1,1,3,3,0,0,1,2,1,5,1,2,5,2,1,0,0,2,1,3,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,2,0,1,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,4,1,3,1,3,0,2,1,1,3,1,1,1,4,1,3,3,0,0,0,3,1,1,1,3),
  total=c(rep(10,21),9,rep(10,11),8,rep(10,81))
)%>%
  # factors for model
  mutate(trt=factor(trt,
                    levels=c("ctrl","trt1","trt2","trt3","trt4","trt5")),
         time=factor(time,
                     levels=c(0:6)*5))->df
```

I used the MASS package to fit a model as shown here:

```r
# fit model
MASS::glm.nb(bad~time*trt+offset(log(total)),
             data=df)->mod
summary(mod)
```

To check the fit of the model I used DHARMa:

```r
# check model fit
DHARMa::simulateResiduals(mod)%>%plot()
```

and got the resulting plot, which seems to imply a good fit:
[image: DHARMa residual]
I then used emmeans to compare the EMMs to the means from the raw dataset, but found that the standard errors from the model were very high. There are results that seem significant from the graph, but the p-values are relatively high (I'm guessing from the high standard error?)

```
se<-function(x,na=T)# x is a numeric list, na functions the same as na.rm (defaults to T)
{
  if(na==T)
  {x<-na.omit(x)}
  return(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)))
}
# check model compared to data
# get means and standard errors for dataset
df%>%
  # standardize by total sample since some were less than 10
  mutate(bad.std=bad/total*10)%>%
  # means and SEs
  group_by(trt,time)%>%
  summarise(means=mean(bad.std),
            ses=se(bad.std),
            .groups="keep")->y
# get emmeans and standard errors from model
emmeans::emmeans(mod,
                 trt.vs.ctrl~trt*time)$emmeans%>%
  as.data.frame()%>%
  # drop NA cols
  subset(!is.na(emmean))%>%
  # back transform from log()
  mutate(mean.trans=exp(emmean),
         se.trans=exp(SE))%>%
  # combine with raw dataset
  inner_join(y,by=c("trt","time"))%>%
  # reorganize for plotting
  mutate(trans=paste(mean.trans,se.trans),
         og=paste(means,ses))%>%
  # declutter columns
  select(trt,time,trans,og)%>%
  pivot_longer(cols=c(trans,og),
               names_to="dataset")%>%
  rowwise()%>%
  mutate(means=str_split(value," ")[[1]][1]%>%as.numeric(),
         ses=str_split(value," ")[[1]][2]%>%as.numeric())%>%
  # plot to compare
  ggplot(aes(x=time,
             fill=dataset))+
    geom_col(aes(y=means),
             position=position_dodge())+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=means-ses,
                      ymax=means+ses),
                  position=position_dodge())+
    facet_grid(.~trt,
               scales="free")
```

Which gives me the resulting plot:
[image: Comparing means and SEs]
I would like to compare the treatments with the controls using Dunnett's test:

```
emmeans::emmeans(mod,
                 trt.vs.ctrl~trt*time)$contrasts
```

and compare treatments at different treatment times:

```
emmeans::emmeans(mod,
                 pairwise~trt|time)$contrasts
```

Is there something wrong with the model or am I using the emmeans package improperly? Looking at the raw data in the bar plot it would seem that some treatment times in trt3 and trt4 are significant compared to the control, but the standard error from the model is too high to show any significance. What am I missing?

Comment: We have an impressive amount of detail in the plots, but you don't even show the SEs that you think are too big. I want to see at least some of the EMMs and contrasts thereof. But that said, I'd not be surprised by large SEs when you have sample sizes of 10. The SEs will be smaller if you look at broader sets if marginal means.